# Why is Java's file browser so old-looking?

Tags: java

I'm using a piece of software called [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/) on Linux Mint 17. The software is based on Java.

My Java is as follows:

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

When I want to open a new file in this software, I'm presented with a file browser directly from the early 1990s, so search ability, no favourite places list, just my `/` directory:

[image: OpenJDK File Browser]

My question is: is this due to my version of OpenJDK, to a problem with Java in general (perhaps specifically, Java on Linux?), or is this something the developers of the software might be able to do something about?

Comment: This looks like the standard appearance of JFileChooser.

Comment: Bonus question: What can be used across platforms?

Comment: OTOH, if you just want the OS' look and feel, there is always `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

Comment: For anyone who's interested in the Gephi-specific angle of this (which may be no one), I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/960).

Answer (score 7):

It's not Java, it's Swing.

Java SE includes Swing, a cross-platform UI toolkit. But by design, most of Swing is not implemented by native controls.

The Swing file browser is not a native dialog.

Updates to native dialogs do not affect it. Enhancements require that the work in Swing become a priority to Oracle.

You can make enhancement requests at [bugs.java.com](http://bugs.java.com/). There is this existing request: [JDK-6689314 : JFileChooser should support custom "favorite places" instd of closed ShellFolder](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6689314).

Another alternative is to use a cross-platform UI toolkit for Java that does use native dialogs. The [Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT)](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) is one such toolkit. It's file dialog is the native file dialog. (Though, at the time of this writing, its folder chooser, while native, is still rather primitive.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer (By Andy), have a look at [Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) which can be used to change the appearance of swing components.

This is how a [Nimbus Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) looks like (from the above link):

[image]